# UPDATE query doesn't implicate database

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have a problem with a UPDATE query.

The `UPDATE` doesn't update the database at all...

It feels like the `command.ExecuteNonQuery()` doesn't happen.

Here is the code:

```
-- The Connection was opened before --
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand command = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
command.Connection = connection;

command.CommandText = "UPDATE users SET user_name=@userName, pass_word=@pass, Uname=@Uname WHERE id=@id";

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", theId);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", userName);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pass);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Uname", Uname);

command.ExecuteNonQuery();

Response.Redirect("~/profile.cshtml");
```

Thanks for any help

Etay

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: Also: try to get back the number of rows updated - like this: `int rowsUpdated =  command.ExecuteNonQuery();` - what value do you get back?

Comment: Does `theId` exist in the table?

Comment: Tnx, succeed it :)

Comment: @EtayZaslavsky Please consider either adding the solution as an answer and accept it, or deleting the question all together. this way, other people will know that the problem is solved.